# RabbitMQ - need to close all connections, but close_all_connections doesn't work

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

We have a set of client PCs running a Windows application that is a client that opens connections to an instance of RabbitMQ 3.7.7 (Erlang 20.3) running on a Windows 2016 server.

Our client application opens a connection on startup.  If it can't open the connection, because there is an error (such as the maximum connection limit having been reached on RabbitMQ), it displays an error message.

There is a *bug in our application where it sometimes leaves the connections open*.  We can't fix the bug (yet) because *patching the application this side of 1st January is out of the question*.

So naturally we want to tell RabbitMQ to close all the connections (we could do this overnight - no one should leave the application running overnight - but if we closed them in the daytime it wouldn't really matter: the RabbitMQ-related features of the client application aren't needed or used until the middle of next month, except for the opening of the connections, which can't be turned off).

But restarting RabbitMQ leaves them all open.  And **rabbitmqctl close_all_connections --global** also doesn't close the connections (perhaps it sends a close message to the client but if the client is no longer listening, leaves the connection open).

Is there anything we can do to force RabbitMQ to close all the connections without writing our own application in Erlang to terminate the processes?

[*Update*: We will fix it the proper way instead now, but perhaps the question should be left here in case it helps someone else?]

Comment: You failed to specify what platform the RabbitMQ server runs on. I am assuming unix? This could probably be done with a simple shell script, but you're looking for a general solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Good point, thank you.  It's actually Windows Server 2016. [Added to question] Next time I post a question I'll remember to include those details!